# Use enumerate environment without new creating new paragraph

Tags: spacing, enumerate, paragraphs, parskip

I want to increase the space between paragraphs but not the space between `eunumerate` environment and it's containing paragraph.

Assume I have following document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\textbf{First paragraph:}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item some text:
        $$
            \left\{
                \begin{array}{c}
                    x_{1} = 000000  \\
                    x_{2} = 000001                  
                \end{array}                         
            \right. 
       $$
    \item
        $$
            \left\{
                \begin{array}{c}
                    x_{1} = 111111  \\
                    x_{2} = 100000                  
                \end{array}                         
            \right.
        $$
\end{enumerate}

\textbf{Second paragraph}
\end{document}
```

I want to increase space between last item and second paragraph. To increase the space between paragraphs, I used following command:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
```

Now my document is as below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}
\textbf{First paragraph:}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item some text:
        $$
            \left\{
                \begin{array}{c}
                    x_{1} = 000000  \\
                    x_{2} = 000001                  
                \end{array}                         
            \right. 
       $$
    \item
        $$
            \left\{
                \begin{array}{c}
                    x_{1} = 111111  \\
                    x_{2} = 100000                  
                \end{array}                         
            \right.
        $$
\end{enumerate}

\textbf{Second paragraph}
\end{document}
```

But this will increase the space between `enumerate` list and its preceding text also:
[image]

I think this happens because `enumerate` environment creates a new paragraph, **Is there any way to prevent it creating new paragraph**? Can I do it without using any external package?

Comment: Can't you turn it off right before enumerate environment and turn it on right after it ends?

Comment: If it works you can define a custom enumerate-like environment that overrides the default and basically do that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

By use of the package `enumitem` this is simple:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for "cases"
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{topsep = 2\baselineskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]

\lipsum[66]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item some text:
        \[
            \begin{cases} 
                    x_{1} = 000000  \\
                    x_{2} = 000001
            \end{cases}
       \]
    \item and more text
        \[
            \begin{cases}
                    x_{1} = 11111  \\
                    x_{2} = 10000
            \end{cases}
       \]
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

Off-topic: use of TeX notation `$$` for display style math is in LaTeX deprecated. Instead it you can use `\[` ... `\]` or `begin{equation*}` ... `\end{equation*}`.

[image]